# Having issues with Select statement in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok so I am having issues selecting the data I want from the table in MySQL. The database connection is successful and active, I started a session before anything else, and the Session is created on login and working. The issue is this pice of code and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Authentication WHERE `id` LIKE ('.$_SESSION['id'].')';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like so:

```
<?php 
$session = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Authentication WHERE `id` LIKE '%$session%'";
?>
```

However, as @nody says, if your id is an integer use *equal to* operator instead of `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Authentication WHERE `id` LIKE '".$_SESSION['id']."'';
```

Comment: if your id is integer the use equal to operator instead of LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check ur **table name correct or not**.
Check your Authentication table id column data type.
if it is varchar ,it should be

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Authentication WHERE `id` LIKE "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"';
```

if it is Integer

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Authentication WHERE `id` LIKE '.$_SESSION['id'];
```

see this for more
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html